# Laravel app.js and app.css why need to use ? Can we removed those?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

I am new learner on Laravel.

I am using **Laravel** **5.3**.But I want Use **Bootstrap** **css** and **Js**.
But Laravel have default `app.css` and `app.js`. 
Hare  `app.css` actually **Bootstrap** **CSS** and also `app.js` work like Bootstarp **js**.
But can i delete `app.js` and `app.css` and can i use custom version Bootstrap **CSS** & **JS** ?

So I need to know why we will be use this two files ?

Answer (score 5):

You can delete them, read the following lines:

**CSS**

Laravel Elixir provides a clean, expressive API over compiling SASS or Less, which are extensions of plain CSS that add variables, mixins, and other powerful features that make working with CSS much more enjoyable.

In this document, we will briefly discuss CSS compilation in general; however, you should consult the full Laravel Elixir documentation for more information on compiling SASS or Less.

**JavaScript**

Laravel does not require you to use a specific JavaScript framework or library to build your applications. In fact, you don't have to use JavaScript at all. However, Laravel does include some basic scaffolding to make it easier to get started writing modern JavaScript using the Vue library. Vue provides an expressive API for building robust JavaScript applications using components.

[Complete Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/frontend)

Answer (score 4):

Laravel default CSS and JS files are safe to remove.

However, these styles will be used in the following places by default, so please be taken care of it.

1. Default Welcome page
2. Laravel auth pages
3. Default error page

If you are using custom themes or your own styles, you can use Laravel Elixer to compile them and which will create app.css for style files and app.js for javascript related files.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/frontend